# Native localtime() segfaults

Tags: raku, nativecall

I seem to be doing something wrong in this attempt to expose the `localtime` functionality in Perl 6:

```
use NativeCall;
my class TimeStruct is repr<CStruct> {
    has int32 $!tm_sec;
    has int32 $!tm_min;
    has int32 $!tm_hour;
    has int32 $!tm_mday;
    has int32 $!tm_mon;
    has int32 $!tm_year;
    has int32 $!tm_wday;
    has int32 $!tm_yday;
    has int32 $!tm_isdst;
    has Str   $!tm_zone;
    has long  $!tm_gmtoff;
}

sub localtime(uint32 $epoch --> TimeStruct) is native {*}
dd localtime(time);  # segfault
```

Running under `perl6-lldb-m`, I get:

```
Process 82758 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5ae5dda1)
    frame #0: 0x00007fffe852efb4 libsystem_c.dylib`_st_localsub + 13
libsystem_c.dylib`_st_localsub:
->  0x7fffe852efb4 <+13>: movq   (%rdi), %rax
    0x7fffe852efb7 <+16>: movq   %rax, -0x20(%rbp)
    0x7fffe852efbb <+20>: movq   0x8e71d3e(%rip), %rbx     ; lclptr
    0x7fffe852efc2 <+27>: testq  %rbx, %rbx
Target 0: (moar) stopped.
```

Any obvious things I'm doing wrong here?

UPDATE: the final working solution:

```
class TimeStruct is repr<CStruct> {
    has int32 $.tm_sec;    # *must* be public attributes
    has int32 $.tm_min;
    has int32 $.tm_hour;
    has int32 $.tm_mday;
    has int32 $.tm_mon;
    has int32 $.tm_year;
    has int32 $.tm_wday;
    has int32 $.tm_yday;
    has int32 $.tm_isdst;
    has long  $.tm_gmtoff; # these two were
    has Str   $.time_zone; # in the wrong order
}

sub localtime(int64 $epoch is rw --> TimeStruct) is native {*}

my int64 $epoch = time;  # needs a separate definition somehow
dd localtime($epoch);
```

Comment: I am checking several things, and all segfault; I have the impression that the number returned by Perl 6 `time` is simply too big to be held in an `uint32`. Have you tried to use also the native `time`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`localtime()` expects a pointer of type `time_t*` as argument. Assuming `time_t` and `uint32_t` are compatible types on your particular platform,

```
sub localtime(uint32 $epoch is rw --> TimeStruct) is native {*}
my uint32 $t = time;
dd localtime($t);
```

should do it (though you won't get to see anything unless you make your attributes public).

I'm a bit surprised that your `time_t` isn't a 64-bit type, and having just googled `apple time.h`, I also suspect the last two attributes in your struct declaration are in the wrong order...

Comment: I get an error with this solution, and I don't really see how it solves the problem, except that the `is rw` seems to fix the segmentation fault. This yields the error `Native call expected argument that references a native integer, but got P6int
  in method CALL-ME at /home/jmerelo/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.04/install/share/perl6/sources/24DD121B5B4774C04A7084827BFAD92199756E03 (NativeCall) line 581
  in block <unit> at localtime-native.p6 line 23
`

Comment: @jjmerelo: for some reason, using an anonymous inline variable doesn't work; if you add a separate declaration, it works over here...

Comment: it does not segfault, but just prints " TimeStruct.new ". Also, `atomicint` can be used instead of `uint32`, with the same result.

Comment: @jjmerelo: that's because liz has declared all her attribute private...

Comment: @jjmerelo: cf my suspicion that the last two attributes are switched, ie `$!tm_zone` won't contain a valid address; you could try the opposite order, or just make only the first couple of attributes public so you can check that at least those will contain the expected values...

Comment: It appears the MacOS `man localtime` documentation does not match reality.  Christoph++ for pointing out the sore spots.